# ini4j store not working

Tags: java, store, ini4j

Following the simple ini4j tutorial I wrote a class to read and write JDBC connections.
Here is what I do when clicking on the dialog buttons:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    JButton b = (JButton)ae.getSource();

    if (b == save || b == load) {
        try {
            Ini ini;
            String section = name.getText();

            if (b == load) {
                System.out.println("Loading " + section);

                ini = new Ini(new File(cfgname));
                driver.setText(ini.get(section, "Driver"));
                url.setText(ini.get(section, "URL"));
                username.setText(ini.get(section, "User"));
                password.setText(ini.get(section, "Password"));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Saving " + section);

                ini = new Ini(new File(cfgname));
                ini.put(section, "Driver", driver.getText());
                ini.put(section, "URL", url.getText());
                ini.put(section, "User", username.getText());
                ini.put(section, "Password", password.getPassword());
                ini.store();
            } // endif b

        } catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
            System.out.println(cfgname + ": not found " + fe);
            setVisible(false);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe);
            setVisible(false);
        } // end try/catch

    } else {        
        id = (ae.getSource() == ok);
        setVisible(false);
    } // endif b
```

} // end of actionPerformed

Reading works well but writing when hitting "save" does the following:

New section and values are written in memory (I can reload them)
But the File is not updated and remains the same.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the following code:

```
try {
    fontOption.store(new FileOutputStream("config/font.conf"));
} catch(IOException e) {
    System.err.println("font: cannot load font.conf or default.conf");
}
```

... that is stored in the file changes.